# Xcode bitcode on and off makes no difference

Tags: ios, xcode, bitcode

> ld: '/Users/falv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-gflhgpgrdfxqnhdvnghrzrzkkfzm/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement(APMEventAggregates.o)' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/falv/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Unity-iPhone-gflhgpgrdfxqnhdvnghrzrzkkfzm/Build/Products/ReleaseForRunning-iphoneos/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport/GoogleAppMeasurement.framework/GoogleAppMeasurement' for architecture arm64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tried bitcode at yes and no for the Target and also tried bitcode at yes and no for the build Pod build settings. This is from google latest unity plugin. Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v7.4.1

Comment: You must set bitcode to NO for GoogleAppMeasurement target in Pods

Comment: Setting bitcode to NO results in the error seen. Setting bitcode to YES results in the error seen. Changing the bitcode setting has no impact.

Comment: Ended up resolving issue. The higher level bitcode setting was set to YES and changing this to NO resolved the issue. Higher level than Pods build settings.